# Change in surface tension of soapy water as oil is added

Tags: surface-chemistry

I am wondering about how the surface tension of clean soapy water changes as oil is added to it?  Is the change gradual or is it abrupt as the amount of oil added exceeds the amount of soap available to surround the oil.  So if the surface tension of clean soapy water is 25 dynes/cm, then as I add oil, will that surface tension go up or will it stay essentially the same until the amount of oil added exceeds the amount of soap needed.  Or perhaps something else happens??

Comment: Oil will reduce the surface tension of water, as will soap. However, depending on the soap used, the concentration of soap, and it’s ability to form micelles, adding oil might pull surfactant molecules away from the surface and damper the surface tension lower effect of the soap by forming micelles. However, adding to much oil might cause the micelles to burst.